# Allow switching/impersonating only to particular users in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, switch-statement

**EXPLANATION**

Allowing user to switch to any other user is easy in Symfony2. My question is, how to allow certain user to switch only to certain other users? I'm using FOSUserBundle as my users provider.

**EXAMPLE**

There is 5 users, UserA, UserB, UserC, UserD, UserE, but only 3 of them are linked together.

UserA can switch to UserB and UserC

UserB can switch to UserA and UserC

UserC can switch to UserA and UserB

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could possibly implement this type of thing by overriding the default SwitchUserListener.

The parameter you would override is: `security.authentication.switchuser_listener.class`

For example, in parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
  security.authentication.switchuser_listener.class: My\Project\Security\Listener\SwitchUserListener
```

Where, in your custom listener class, you'd implement `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface` and use the existing `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener` class as a basis for your custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to impersonate Admin Users in to Regular user there are some examples :)

https://gist.github.com/1589120

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#impersonating-a-user

Comment: As I understand, once user has ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, he/she can append ?_switch_user=anyusernamethatexists to the url and is able to switch to that user. How to allow user to switch only to certain other users?

Comment: I suppose that is there some switch user listener. I will check in the symfony source.

Comment: Have you checked the source yet? Thanks for help!

Comment: The Symfony documentation link has changed: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Veonik, a (maybe dirty) way to do that

Add a role with that syntax :

```
 ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH_{usertype}
```

For example add ROLE_A to userA :

```
ROLE_A:
 - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH_USERTYPEB
 - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH_USERTYPEC
```

Declare your own SwitchUserListener service in yml :

```
security.authentication.switchuser_listener:
  class: %security.authentication.switchuser_listener.class%
  public: false
  abstract: true
  tags:
      - { name: monolog.logger, channel: security}
  arguments: 
   - @security.context
   - null
   - @security.user_checker
   - null
   - @security.access.decision_manager
   - @logger
   - _switch_user
   - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH 
   - @event_dispatcher
   - @security.role_hierarchy
```

In SwitchUserListener::attemptSwitchUser method

```
private function attemptSwitchUser(Request $request)
{
 ....
 CODE BEFORE
 ....
    $user = $this->provider->loadUserByUsername($username);
    $rtoSwith = $this->getRolesToSwitchTo($token->getRoles());
    $accessGranted = false;
    foreach ($rtoSwith as $suType) {
        $instance = ucfirst(strtolower($suType));
        if ($user instanceof $instance) {
            $accessGranted = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$accessGranted) {

        throw new AccessDeniedException('Access Denied, not allowed to switch to type : '.get_class($user));
    }
 ....
 CODE AFTER 
 ....
 return $token
}

protected function getRolesToSwitchTo($roles){

    $rts = array();
    foreach ($this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles($roles) as $role) {

        $tmp = explode("ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH_", $role->getRole());

        if(isset($tmp[1])){
            $rts[] = $tmp[1];
        }
    }

    return $rts;
}
```

Tell me if you have another solution
 ++