# Symfony 2 allow impersonating users only on subset of users

Tags: php, symfony, impersonation

I'm trying to implement an application where the admin can impersonate any user. This is fine with Symfony 2 - Just give them the "ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH" role.

But the system also knows "resellers" which should be able to impersonate users too, but only the users which are associated to the reseller!

I could not get anything regarding this from the Symfony 2 documentation nor the cook book.

How would it be possible to restrict a reseller to only be able to switch to users he should be able to switch to?

I think voters may be a way but I am a bit lost here.

Comment: [Here's some info that you might find handy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371438/switching-users-in-symfony2)

Comment: Thanks! SO did not mention this in the suggestions while typing the question. Odd thing ;)

Comment: No problem! Probably not since the title of that article wasn't very good - BUT I was able to find it after only a bit of Googling! I'll put an edit on the title of that article and see if it'll get accepted. Meanwhile I'll mark this as a duplicate

Comment: I think I googled the wrong term. But hey, my mother tongue is german not english :D

Comment: As far as I can tell, your English is excellent. Cheers!