# how to change global session for user in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

comment changer la session d'utilisateur connecte à une autre session d'utilisateur j'utilise fosuserbundle dans Symfony2

ex: utilisateur connecter us1
changer session courante à us2

Comment: can you try it in english? So more people can help you.

Comment: i want to change current seesion for user1 to another user for exemple i'm connected with user1 and i want to change global session from user1 to user2 and i will be connected as user2

Comment: this is how i get current user session $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

Answer (score 0):

In your security.yml allow switch user:

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    admin:
        pattern:      /admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            ...
            failure_path:   null
            ...
            ...
        anonymous:    true
        switch_user: true
```

Then to switch between users:

```
 To switch to another user
 http://example.com/somewhere?_switch_user=UserName
 To switch back to the original user
 http://example.com/somewhere?_switch_user=_exit
```

Try to look at the symfony documentation also : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

Comment: thanks for your answer is it possible to switch to another user from controller ?

Comment: I found a similar post that can help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371438/allow-switching-impersonating-only-to-particular-users-in-symfony2