# How to get user roles before impersonation?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to build a system where some user groups are allowed to switch to a certain number of users, and the admin group can switch to ANY user. My user manager is provided by `FOSUserBundle` I have set up security voters to achieve this, to check the user roles after the switch has occurred. I created a new voter attribute called `'IMPERSONATION'` and called `denyAccessUnlessGranted` on the first line of the main (homepage) controller that is run after the user switching.

Inside my voter, I first get the user objects for both the impersonated and impersonator users. I try to get the impersonator user by doing the following (as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/impersonating_user.html)).

```
foreach ($tokenStorage->getToken()->getRoles() as $role) {
    if ($role instanceof SwitchUserRole) {
        $impersonatorUser = $role->getSource()->getUser();
        break;
    }
```

Then, I want to return true (grant access) if the `$impersonatorUser` is a super admin:

```
if ($impersonatorUser->isSuperAdmin()) { return true; }
// .. 
// ... other voter logic
```

However, when I try to switch user from a user that has the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role to a user that has a non-admin role, this line is never executed. When I do a `var_dump`, I found that `$impersonatorUser->isSuperAdmin()` returns false, and `$impersonatorUser->getRoles` shows that the user only has the `ROLE_USER` role. And since the logic after this line returns false, the voter denies access and the switch results in Access Denied error.

The user seems to have lost the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role after switching. Is this a bug with FosUserBundle?

My role hierarchies are set as follows:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_MENTOR
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

The user switching option is set as follows:

```
switch_user: { role: ROLE_MENTOR }
```

How can I check for the roles of the user before switching, so I can control who can switch users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOSUserBundle only provides a user management system, it has nothing to do with Symfony Security and access management.

If you use symfony switch user feature to impersonate user, then you'll have an extra role `ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN` on your impersonated user, which can  be checked [(see documentation)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html)

I don't know the best solution to implement your feature, but perhaps this could help ([Allow switching/impersonating only to particular users in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371438/allow-switching-impersonating-only-to-particular-users-in-symfony2))